# Airflow - Error raised from sqlalchemy when try to run a TaskInstance

Tags: sqlalchemy, airflow

I'm testing the execution of a crawler inside of the airflow structure. If I ran the following script, everything works fine and the payloads is printed.

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import BaseOperator, TaskInstance
from hooks.crawler_hook import CrawlerHook

from datetime import datetime
import time

class CrawlerOperator(BaseOperator):
    def __init__(self, conn_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.conn_id = conn_id

    def execute(self):
        hook = CrawlerHook(conn_id=self.conn_id)
        print(hook.run())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CrawlerOperator(task_id='test_run').execute()
```

But when I try to run a TaskInstance inside a DAG, I've got the an error and cannot understand why:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with DAG(dag_id="DAG1", start_date=datetime.now(), catchup=False) as dag:
        to = CrawlerOperator(task_id="test_run")
        ti = TaskInstance(task=to)
        ti.run()
```

The error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/../.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 67, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/../.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1123, in get_dagrun
    dr = session.query(DagRun).filter(DagRun.dag_id == self.dag_id, DagRun.run_id == self.run_id).one()
  File "/home/../.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3500, in one
    raise orm_exc.NoResultFound("No row was found for one()")
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound: No row was found for one()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using it in some kind of unit test. What you are missing (and as the error indicates) is a DagRun:

```
from airflow.models import DagRun
DagRun(dag_id=self.dag.dag_id, execution_date=timezone.utcnow(), run_id="test")
ti.dag_run = dag_run
```

This is needed because tasks are associated to a DagRun not to a DAG.
DAG can have many DagRuns.

You can see example in one of the unit tests in Airflow [codebase](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/60b72dd8f5161f0e00f29a9de54522682f7cd5f6/tests/providers/amazon/aws/operators/test_dms_describe_tasks.py#L87-L94).

Comment: It worked!!! Other thing it was missing is the `context` parameter inside the execute function. Thnks